# what does <body_name> and <frame_name> tag of gazebo IMU plugin imply?

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-melodic, gazebo-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to implement a IMU sensor in gazebo using this tutorial :http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins

```
 <gazebo reference="imu_link">
<gravity>true</gravity>
<sensor name="imu_sensor" type="imu">
  <always_on>true</always_on>
  <update_rate>100</update_rate>
  <visualize>true</visualize>
  <topic>__default_topic__</topic>
  <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_imu_sensor.so" name="imu_plugin">
    <topicName>imu</topicName>
    <bodyName>imu_link</bodyName>
    <updateRateHZ>10.0</updateRateHZ>
    <gaussianNoise>0.0</gaussianNoise>
    <xyzOffset>0 0 0</xyzOffset>
    <rpyOffset>0 0 0</rpyOffset>
    <frameName>imu_link</frameName>
    <initialOrientationAsReference>false</initialOrientationAsReference>
  </plugin>
  <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
</sensor>
```

I am assuming that <frame_name> corresponds to the TF name of the link to which sensor is attached . However I am not sure what  tag refers to.

It will be very helpful if some one can provide links to a more detailed page where all the tags are explained.

Thank you !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362206/what-does-%3Cbody_name%3E-and-%3Cframe_name%3E-tag-of-gazebo-imu-plugin-imply?/) by [Shiva_uchiha](https://answers.ros.org/users/37455/shiva_uchiha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 117 on 2020-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @Shiva_uchiha,

First of all I want to clarify that the `gazebo_ros_imu` plugin is not the same as the `gazebo_ros_imu_sensor` plugin. The first one is a model plugin and the second one a sensor plugin, hence, they are attach to different things in the simulation.

Both use the `frameName` parameter to fill the `sensor_msgs::Imu` message header the plugins produce.

On the other hand, the `bodyName` name param is only used by the `gazebo_ros_imu` plugin to assert that the model to which the plugin is attached exists by that name in the Gazebo world. This has to be done like that to ensure the plugin is properly loaded in the model.

If you have doubts about its functioning you can check the github repo containing the implementation of all official Gazebo plugins [here](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs).

Hope it helps you.

Regards.

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1